# Can I use same bundle identifier for iOS and tvOS apps?

Tags: ios, app-store, tvos

As the title says, a simple question: can I use the same bundle identifier for an iOS and an tvOS application, or do they need to be unique across the whole of Apple’s app ecosystem?

I’m wanting to create apps for a video on demand site and offer apps on both iOS, and eventually tvOS. They’ll be different codebases (due to using different SDKs to target different platforms), but they’ll essentially be the same app (as in offer the same functionality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can share the same bundle ids even if the codebase is completely different. You just need to treat them as the same app in the iTunes Connect (by adding tvOS version to iOS version).

I have submitted my first dual-OS app last week, and it was quite straightforward. It is very much like submitting two separate apps (two sets of screenshots, two app descriptions, two binaries). The only thing shared is the app id and app name (NOTE: you can't not have two different names).

So far, Apple has approved only the iOS app and migrated it to the store (see the link below), and rejected the tvOS app for an UI issue, which I am fixing it right now. Just like two different apps, the review processes are independent as well.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudreaders-pdf-cbz-cbr/id1051119890?mt=8

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like your scenario is pretty much the same as mine. Keep me updated on how your project goes!

Comment: "can't not have two different names" ∴ the apps must have different names?